# What is the best laptop to buy to run latest version of Cropster?

Tags: roasting

I’m about to purchase a new laptop for my roasting business and I would like to purchase the one on which Cropster runs best.

Comment: This is the wrong stack exchange in my opinion. It's not a coffee related topic.

Comment: I guess you have low standards for the people who roast your coffee. You must think tracking the roast curve is unimportant.

Comment: You must be some kind of psychic to be able to judge me and my life just by my name (Hint: avocado is not even a real one). Psychic or not though, your question is still in the wrong stackexchange. There's one specific for hardware recommendations for example. And please don't make me explain why your question is not coffee related. I'm sure you will be able to figure it out by yourself.

Comment: Agree to disagree

Comment: Tried helping, but you obviously prefer to just be passive aggressive. That's fine with me, after all you are the one asking for help.

Comment: This is not a coffee question, it’s a “which computer is suitable for *task X*” - which incidentally is a roasting program. Why don’t you check the system requirements for your software, then ask your local retailer or our sister site.

Comment: Actually, I think this may be somewhat related. Cropster is special software hardly known by people who are not professional coffee roasters. Also, this software requires special I/O for thermocouples, etc. So, our sister site may not be helpful. Still, I advise Jonathan to contact Cropster support as they have dedicated knowledge on the topic.

Comment: @MTSan As per the Cropster website, the special hardware is either supplied by them or an Ethernet cable will do - depending on the roaster. Couldn’t find specific hardware requirements, they write something along the line of “any average computer will do if it’s not too old”. I found no indicator that unusual HW ports are required. And if the software runs on a Mac, it *can’t* be ;-)

Comment: @Stephie you could remove the word computer and insert “grinder”, “water heater”, “scale”, “filter”, “warehouse space”, “ventilation” etc.  All of these objects in the above cases are not themselves coffee, but are related to the coffee making process.

Comment: @avocado1 I am not interested in the opinions of someone whose expertise is in software and hardware, but in coffee roasting.  Because this is not your expertise and you do not understand why it’s related, does not mean it does not belong.  On the contrary, you are being uninviting to those who might broaden the usefulness of this SE page, but who are now much less inclined to do so.

Comment: @JonathanMuse I strongly recommend you tone it down a bit. Everyone is welcome to have an opinion and as long as they express it nicely, it’s not an issue. But all SE sites are very sensitive when the [“be nice”](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) rule is ignored. In my opinion, you are skating on thin ice. Personally, I have a few issues with your question, apart from what I wrote previously, asking for “the best X” can easily be seen as primarily opinion-based. Asking which features are necessary or other important details would be ok, imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer from Cropster FAQ, accessed May 2018:

Operating System
    •   Windows Vista or later
    •   Mac OS 
    •   Linux
Minimum Requirements
    •   Intel Pentium D or AMD Athlon 64 (K8) 2.6 GHz
    •   RAM: 2GB
    •   HDD: 100MB
    •   USB standard-A port or a compatible adapter
    •   Display: 1366 x 768 resolution
    •   Java 6 Release 45
Recommended Requirements
    •   CPU: Intel Core i3 or AMD Athlon II (K10) 2.8 GHz
    •   RAM: 4GB
    •   HDD: 500MB
    •   USB standard-A port or a compatible adapter
    •   Display: 1920 x 1080 resolution
    •   Latest release of Java from java.com
Software Requirements:
    •   Please note that some users experience issues running the Roasting Intelligence while using a mismatched version of Java for their operating system (32 or 64 bit), while using certain versions of Java 7, or while multiple versions of Java are installed
A stable internet connection is required for the RI to download profiles, green lots, machines, workers, authenticate usernames, and upload roasts to our servers. You'll need to download and run the RI while connected to the internet at least once; afterwards, you can roast without an internet connection, but will need to connect to update your inventory or reference curves and to receive updates.

The RI will not run on a Chromebook.